# How to programmatically uncheck/check checkbox in angularjs latest version (1.4.0-beta.5)?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

This is the code in jsfiddle using version 1.1.1. This is the working code by the way. What it does is uncheck the checkbox if the button is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/j2a53gwj/2/

I have the same exact code but the angularjs version is 1.4.0-beta.5. http://plnkr.co/edit/hUE2xSI8PCads8WOumLx?p=streamer

```
angular.module("CheckAllModule", [])
    .controller("checkboxController", function ($scope) {


     $scope.clickme = function() {
      alert("x");
      $scope.master = false;
      //$scope.ss.Selected = false;
    };

  });
```

The code isnt working in this version.

I know, I have already asked this question before, but because of the version upgrade, the code didn't work which makes my question valid.

How will I do it in angularjs latest version? or if the version is not the problem, then what is? I did copy paste the code so that I know I'm using the same code only with different versions.

Comment: try the 1.4 version in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with angular version `1.4.0-beta.5`

See **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/50djdqkw/1/)**

Angular version `1.4.0-beta.5` is included from the external resources panel.

> I have the same exact code but the angularjs version is 1.4.0-beta.5. http://plnkr.co/edit/hUE2xSI8PCads8WOumLx?p=streamer

Definitely not the same code as the fiddle, but this plnkr does not work because you forgot to link the script file from the `index.html`, therefore the `ng-click` handler function is not even executed.